# App Engine <threadsafe> element missing error

Tags: xml, google-app-engine, error-handling, thread-safety

So I have this error that i've seen many people have:

```
appengine-web.xml does not contain a <threadsafe> element.
```

But the solution always provided is to just add

```
<threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
```

to the appengine-web.xml file. This is my appengine-web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
  <application>dummy</application>
  <version>1</version>
  <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
  <!-- Configure java.util.logging -->
  <system-properties>
    <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/>
  </system-properties>
</appengine-web-app>
```

And still I get the error that no threadsafe element is found?

Answer (score 1):

I think   `<threadsafe>true</threadsafe>` needs to be the first entry in your appengine-web.xml

Here is my xml withouth error:

```
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <!--<async-session-persistence enabled="true"/>-->
    <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
    <application>dummy</application>

    <version>443</version>
    <sessions-enabled>true</sessions-enabled>
    <inbound-services>
        <service>mail</service>
        <service>xmpp_message</service>
    </inbound-services>
    <system-properties>
      <property name="com.google.gdata.DisableCookieHandler" value="true"/>
    </system-properties>
</appengine-web-app>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, however I cannot confirm that that is the solution. Although I did manage to get it to work after just deleting and retyping the "<application>dummy</application>" part several times. My XML file now looks just like it does in the question, but throws no error anymore.
It shall remain a mystery...